# centering text across panels of an annotated lattice figure

Tags: r, lattice

I have a multi-panel lattice figure.  It has an even number of equal-width columns.  I would like to center text across the columns.

Sometimes, this is easy to do.  For example, the `xlab` and `main` arguments often handle this job nicely.  But I want a more flexible solution.  (I have many strings and want to position them at different heights, but always centered across the columns.)

`grid.text("Label", x = unit(.5, "npc"), y = unit(yPos, "npc"))` will work when the figure has no annotations outside the panel.  But when it does -- for example, when I use the `scales` argument to create row labels -- using `grid.text()` in this way doesn't center the text.  Here is a minimal example:

```
dataToPlot <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, panel = c('a', 'b'))
plot1 <- xyplot(
  y ~ x | panel, 
  data   = dataToPlot,
  layout = c(2,1),
  ylab   = '',
  xlab   = '',
  scales = list(
    x = NULL, 
    y = list(
      draw   = TRUE,
      labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2"),
      at     = c(1.8, 1.4))))
print(plot1)
grid.text("XXX", x = unit(.5, "npc"))
```

The "XXX" isn't centered.  How can I center it?

I suppose that I could draw the figure without the row labels (i.e., without supplying a `scales` argument), use `grid.text("Label", x = unit(.5, "npc"), y = unit(yPos, "npc"))`, and then use `grid.text()` again to draw the row labels.  But is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paul Murrell provides this answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-August/359382.html), which seems to work regardless of the layout (in terms of rows and columns of panels) of the plot:

```
downViewport("plot_01.figure.vp")
grid.text("centred\ntext")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate the viewport tree and place a grob in the grid layout,

```
plot1
seekViewport("plot_01.toplevel.vp")
grid.text("centred\ntext", gp=gpar(col="red"), 
          vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=9, layout.pos.col=9:13))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- this is most helpful.  But in a general sense, I am still not sure of how to center text.  For example, in your code above, you center by using `vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=9, layout.pos.col=9:13)`.  In different figures, the `layout.pos.row` and `layout.pos.col` arguments will need to be different.  How can I figure out what they should be?  (I suppose that this is like asking: how can I learn the layout of "plot_01.toplevel.vp"?)

Comment: the best way, I find, is to read the lattice source code every night before going to bed. `showViewport()` might be of some help too.

Comment: `trellis.focus` might be useful too